# Why are the straight lines in my model distorted when UV unwrapped?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to unwrap a fireplace model. I have marked the seams wherever required but when I try to unwrap it, all the edges of the model are at an angle and are distorted as you can see. I want all the edges to be perfectly straight.

I've already applied the scale in the object mode. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Try this, Press U Unwrap with 'Project from view (bounds)'.That's what you want?

Comment: it won't work in this case since it has an extruded platform and windows.

Comment: As the mesh has tiny faces loops try using Conformal method instead of Angle-Based in Unwrap settings. If you want to use Angle-Based and try to find what happened attach the file please using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so that someone could take a look

Comment: Can you please tell me more about confrontational and angle-based unwrapping since I'm fairly new to unwrapping? Where can I access them in the unwrap menu? I tried looking that up on the net but not much info is available regarding that.

Comment: @MrZak Thanks for the solution. It worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe all the planes of the fireplace are not at right angle to each other. You can confirm with this script (select the fire place before executing it; the info will be printed on console).

All the angles should be close to 90 (or 0).

```
import bmesh
import bpy
import math

obj = bpy.context.object 
me = obj.data

if me.is_editmode:
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
else:
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(me)

for f1 in bm.faces:
    angleInfo = (f1.index, [round(math.degrees(f1.normal.angle(f2.normal)), 3) \
        for e in f1.edges for f2 in e.link_faces if f1 is not f2])
    print(angleInfo)
```